# CentOS 8 not finding Nignx 1.16 software

Tags: centos, nginx

In my CentOS 8 server, when I update (`yum upgrade`) its not finding the latest version of Nginx software. it stays on `1.14` version.

How to update the latest Nginx version?

```
# yum list nginx --showduplicates
Last metadata expiration check: 2:27:24 ago on Sun 20 Sep 2020 03:12:40 PM EDT.
Installed Packages
nginx.x86_64                 1:1.14.1-9.module_el8.0.0+184+e34fea82                  @AppStream
Available Packages
nginx.x86_64                 1:1.14.1-9.module_el8.0.0+184+e34fea82                  AppStream
```

Thanks

SR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the nginx:1.14 yum module enabled. To see what modules are available, run (as root or with sudo):

```
# yum module list nginx
```

To switch to the 1.16 module, run this command:

```
 # yum module reset nginx
 # yum module enable nginx:1.16
```

Read the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/installing_managing_and_removing_user-space_components/introduction-to-modules_using-appstream) on rhel8 module streams.